# Which goodness of fit test to use?

Tags: goodness-of-fit

I have two different vectors and I would like to compare these with each other so I could say that statistically the distributions come from the same sample. The data is below:

X1: 149 144 140 135 131 127 123 119 116 112 109 105 102 100  97  93  89  87  84  81  77  74  70  65  61  57 55  52  51  49  50  51  54  55  56  59  63  66  72  77  83  90

X2: 153 144 138 132 128 125 121 116 111 106 101  98  92  86  82  75  70  65  59  55  52  50  48  46  46  48 50  53  55  58  63  70  78  86

I tried the CramerVonMisesTwoSamples function and calculated p-value from the given u-value, but I am not sure if it gives me accurate results to say anything meaningful. Is there some other test suitable to statistically compare these vectors?

Comment: What's wrong with Cramer von Mises? That is what I'd do. Note that (1) if you run more than one test you need a correction for multiple testing, and (2) you can never say "the samples statistically come from the same distribution" regardless of the p-value - the best you ever get is that there is no evidence against it.

Comment: By the way, you probably mean "the samples come from the same distribution", not the other way round.